# How can I select a new mode for a pin using a device tree file?

Tags: linux, device-tree

I am developing on an [iMX6 Wandboard ARM computer](http://www.wandboard.org). The Wandboard's default configuration only offers 8 GPIO pins for use, though the iMX6 has many more available that may be switched to GPIO mode from their current setting. My project requires more GPIOs and I have been trying to change the mode on some pins to that end.

I am able to modify and compile the iMX6/wandboard device tree files into a DTB and use it on my device (I tested by disabling the HDMI output) but I haven't figured out how to change some pins from their current setting to GPIO-mode.

I'm currently trying to switch the `DISP0` display (`MX6QDL_PAD_DISP0_DAT0 - DAT23` in pinfunc.h below) to GPIO mode because those pins are available on a header on the dev board. I'm currently trying to use these pins from imx6qdl-wandboard.dsti:

```
&iomuxc {
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_hog_1>;

        /* other fields unchanged */
        gpio {
            pinctrl_gpio: gpiogrp {
                fsl,pins = <
                    MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_DA12__GPIO3_IO12   0x4001b0b0 /* GPIO3_12 EDM pin 255 */
                    MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_DA11__GPIO3_IO11   0x4001b0b0 /* GPIO3_11 EDM pin 256 */
                    MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_DA10__GPIO3_IO10   0x4001b0b0 /* GPIO3_10 EDM pin 257 */
                    MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_D27__GPIO3_IO27    0x4001b0b0 /* GPIO3_27 EDM pin 258 */
                    MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_D26__GPIO3_IO26    0x4001b0b0 /* GPIO3_26 EDM pin 259 */
                    MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_BCLK__GPIO6_IO31   0x4001b0b0 /* GPIO6_31 EDM pin 260 */
                    MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_DA8__GPIO3_IO08    0x4001b0b0 /* GPIO3_8  EDM pin 261 */
                    MX6QDL_PAD_ENET_RX_ER__GPIO1_IO24 0x4001b0b0 /* GPIO1_24 EDM pin 262 */
                    MX6QDL_PAD_GPIO_19__GPIO4_IO05    0x4001b0b0 /* GPIO4_5  EDM pin 263 */
                    MX6QDL_PAD_SD3_RST__GPIO7_IO08    0x4001b0b0 /* GPIO7_8  EDM pin 264 */
                    /* my added pins */
                    MX6QDL_PAD_DISP0_DAT0__GPIO4_IO21 0x4001b0b0 /* GPIO4_21 GPIO117 JP1-1*/
                    MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_D21__GPIO3_IO21    0x4001b0b0 /* GPIO3_21 GPIO85 JP2-9 */
                >;
            };
       };
};
```

I first tried using a `status = "disabled";` field on `&ipu2` in imx6qdl-wandboard.dtsi but that didn't allow me to change values through the `/sys/class/gpio` interface. Nor did removing the `ipu2` and `&iomuxc` blocks entirely. I'm at a loss for what to try next. I'm 90% certain these pins can be used for the purpose I'm trying, but this kind of configuration is way beyond my ken.

#### Relevant files from the Wandboard Linux source

- [imx6q-pinfunc.h](https://github.com/wandboard-org/linux/blob/wandboard_imx_3.10.17_1.0.2_ga/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6q-pinfunc.h)         (list of all iMX6 pins and their functions)
- [imx6qdl.dtsi](https://github.com/wandboard-org/linux/blob/wandboard_imx_3.10.17_1.0.2_ga/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6qdl.dtsi)           (base iMX6 settings)
- [imx6q.dtsi](https://github.com/wandboard-org/linux/blob/wandboard_imx_3.10.17_1.0.2_ga/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6q.dtsi)             (quad-core settings)
- [imx6qdl-wandboard.dtsi](https://github.com/wandboard-org/linux/blob/wandboard_imx_3.10.17_1.0.2_ga/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6qdl-wandboard.dtsi) (wandboard-specific settings)
- [imx6q-wandboard.dts](https://github.com/wandboard-org/linux/blob/wandboard_imx_3.10.17_1.0.2_ga/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6q-wandboard.dts)    (a kind of stub that pulls the others together)

Comment: Are you sure there are no other files to define the configurations of gpio. I would rather suggest you to make sure that the GPIOs are actually working. (The GPIO can be configured through code only without using dtsi configuration)

Comment: Yes, I can use the other configured GPIO pins (listed above my changes in the code sample) through sysfs. A few of the 10 listed do not work for reasons unknown but the others are fine. http://forums.wandboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=684

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news, I was finally able to set GPIO mode on some pins of my choosing.

I think the `&iomuxc gpio` node in the wandboard dtsi file is somehow unchangeable or only supports the few pins that are already listed under its group. I spent a lot of time trying to disable different features and re-purpose the corresponding pins under that node with no results.

Based on [this post](http://boundarydevices.com/mx6-device-tree-customization/) on the Boundary Devices blog and [a device tree file](https://github.com/boundarydevices/linux-imx6/blob/boundary-imx_3.10.17_1.0.2_ga/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6qdl-boundary-nolcd.dtsi) for their sabre iMX6 board I decided to try to make my own additional `hog` group and that works. I added a new `&iomuxc` block and overrode the `pinctrl-0` list to include my own `hoggrp` (there was already a `hoggrp-1` so I just made mine `hoggrp-2`).

```
/* at the end of imx6qdl-wandboard.dtsi */
&iomuxc {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <
        &pinctrl_hog_1
        &wes_gpios
    >;

    imx6qdl-wandboard {
        wes_gpios: hoggrp-2 {
            fsl,pins = <
                MX6QDL_PAD_ENET_CRS_DV__GPIO1_IO25 0x4001b0b0 /* GPIO1_25 test point lead */
                MX6QDL_PAD_DISP0_DAT0__GPIO4_IO21  0x4001b0b0 /* GPIO4_21 GPIO117 JP1-1*/
                MX6QDL_PAD_GPIO_5__GPIO1_IO05      0x4001b0b0 /* gpio5 jp2-17 */
                MX6QDL_PAD_GPIO_16__GPIO7_IO11     0x4001b0b0 /* gpio203 jp2-15 */
            >;
        };
    };
};
```

Each of the pins I've used in this group work in sysfs as expected, although using the EIM_D21 pin from my question's code overrides the i2c interface that the EDID data is transmitted on for HDMI, disabling the display. Any unused pin works, though.

(If anyone can tell me what the "hog" is I'd be interested to hear it.)

Comment: A hog just collects up all unused pins, AFAIK.